# Is it possible to make all images in my slideshow full size without stretching or showing scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-resizing

I am looking to display google photos in a random slideshow but the trouble I'm having is each photo is a different size, is there a way I can force all photo to be the same size without stretching. Here is my code so far, any help would be appreciated.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script language="javascript">

    var delay = 10000 //set delay in miliseconds
    var curindex = 0

    var randomimages = new Array()

    randomimages[0] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[1] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[2] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[3] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[4] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[8] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[9] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"
    randomimages[10] = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MyPhotoLink"

    var preload = new Array()

    for (n = 0; n < randomimages.length; n++) {
      preload[n] = new Image()
      preload[n].src = randomimages[n]
    }

    document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="' + randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length))] + '">')

    function rotateimage() {

      if (curindex == (tempindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length)))) {
        curindex = curindex == 0 ? 1 : curindex - 1
      }
      else
        curindex = tempindex

      document.images.defaultimage.src = randomimages[curindex]
    }

    setInterval("rotateimage()", delay)

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max-height and max-width is a good start to avoid clipping them:
(clip option stands already  in another answer)

example

```js
var delay = 5000 //set delay in miliseconds
var curindex = 0

var randomimages = new Array()

randomimages[0] = "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"
randomimages[1] = "https://placeimg.com/1000/880/animals"
randomimages[2] = "https://placeimg.com/240/480/any"
randomimages[3] = "https://placeimg.com/940/80/nature"
randomimages[4] = "https://placeimg.com/100/480/people"
randomimages[8] = "https://placeimg.com/480/980/any"
randomimages[9] = "https://placeimg.com/240/480/tech"
randomimages[10] = "https://placeimg.com/640/280/any"

var preload = new Array()

for (n = 0; n < randomimages.length; n++) {
  preload[n] = new Image()
  preload[n].src = randomimages[n]
}

document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="' + randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length))] + '">')

function rotateimage() {

  if (curindex == (tempindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomimages.length)))) {
    curindex = curindex == 0 ? 1 : curindex - 1
  } else
    curindex = tempindex

  document.images.defaultimage.src = randomimages[curindex]
}

setInterval("rotateimage()", delay)
```

```css
img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  image-orientation: from-image;
  /* optionnal*/
  display: block;
}


/* demo purpose only */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: auto
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, your code worked a treat and I've added in a background colour to fill the voids. A big ask but don't suppose there is a way to automatically rotate landscape images to fit?

Comment: You can try `img {image-orientation: from-image; }` if it stands in the EXIF of the img file. not too sure about the browser support but it should not hurt

Comment: @stan780953 infos here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the property **object fit**

`.fitImage {object-fit: cover; width: 250px; height: 100px}`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.